# getting local storage data as [object Object] in angular login.component.ts

Tags: constructor, local-storage, angular7

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FirebaseService } from "../services/firebase.service";
    import { User } from '../interfaces/user';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
    import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
    import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


      sag: any;
      constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private firebaseService: FirebaseService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private localStorage: LocalStorage) {
        this.sag = localStorage.getItem('user').subscribe(() => { });
        console.log('constructor :'+this.sag);
      }
 ngOnInit() {}
login() {
  var myItem = localStorage.getItem("user");
  console.log('  cookies:' + myItem);
      }
}
```

I am having data in local storage as key 'user' and value as 'HelloUser'.

In constructor console it is printing as [object Object] , but in login() it is printing the correct value when is called by clicking button but ,I want to get value from constructor .

Answer (score 0):

Knowing there is a `sag` object variable declared as public, you can do this following this way:

`this.sag = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('user'));`

Reference: https://gist.github.com/jbail/4364947

Comment: but getting error argument of type observable unknown is not assignable to the parameter type string ..

Comment: Why did you `suscribe` a localstorage.getItem()?

Comment: I am having data in local storage as key 'user' and value as 'HelloUser'.

In constructor console it is printing as [object Object] , but in login() it is printing the correct value when is called by clicking button but ,I want to get value from constructor .